# Textbox within a CheckBox value, desactivate unchecked when I type into the TextBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I generate a Textbox within my Checkbox value. But when I click into the textbox in order to type in something, the checkbox automatically unchecked itself.

```
<span id="TRAVEL_TYPE_1"><input id="TRAVEL_TYPE_0" type="checkbox" onclick="UpdateTravelInformations();">
    </input><label for="TRAVEL_TYPE_0">
  TRP1 : Transports en commun 2ème classe, sur justificatifs
  <div id="TRAVEL_TYPE_1_INFORMATION" class="infoChoixFDM" style="display: block;">
     <input id="MONTANTMAX" class="positive-integer" type="text" value="20" maxlength="5" style="width:50px; text-align:center" runat="server"></input>
   €
  </div>
 </label>
</span>
```

The problem is partially solved on Chrome, when I set checked as false on the click event of MONTANTMAX. But in IE and Firefox it doesnt work...

```
$('#MONTANTMAX').click(function () {
    if (!$.browser.msie) {
        $('#TRAVEL_TYPE input').get(0).checked = false;
}
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Please add a fiddle and please make your problem moe clear..thanks

Comment: you need to show us your UpdateTravelInformations().. cause is think that is where you problem exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to close the `<label>` at the end on the text

```
<span id="TRAVEL_TYPE_1"><input id="TRAVEL_TYPE_0" type="checkbox" onclick="UpdateTravelInformations();">
    </input><label for="TRAVEL_TYPE_0">
  TRP1 : Transports en commun 2ème classe, sur justificatifs</label>
  <div id="TRAVEL_TYPE_1_INFORMATION" class="infoChoixFDM" style="display: block;">
     <input id="MONTANTMAX" class="positive-integer" type="text" value="20" maxlength="5" style="width:50px; text-align:center" runat="server"></input>
   €
  </div>
</span>
```

Otherwise the input will be assigned as a label for the checkbox.

UPDATE: JS solution

```
$(function(){
  $('#MONTANTMAX').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#TRAVEL_TYPE_0[checked=false]').prop('checked', true);
  });                                             
});
```

Comment: I know this must be the logic but all this code is generated automatically in my code behind and I did this in order to put a sentence below my real value. This is all part of a <asp:CheckBoxList>

Comment: So you can't change the html? I will try another method then.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little bit muddled, by the looks of things.

Try this:

```
$('#MONTANTMAX').click(function () {
    $('#TRAVEL_TYPE_0').prop('checked', true);
}
```